# Video in Angular - TypeError Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-video

I'm trying to do some basic video stream work in Angular.  My code is below.  Challenge is I keep getting and error that says...
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'video' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'video' of undefined

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-scanner',
  templateUrl: './scanner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scanner.component.css']
})
export class ScannerComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('video') video: HTMLMediaElement;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cameraCheck();
  }



  cameraCheck() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: {
          facingMode: 'environment'
        }
      })
      .then(function(stream) {
        this.video.srcObject = stream;
        this.video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'true'); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
        this.video.play();
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video #video></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `function(stream)` in the promise handle for `getUserMedia` doesn't seem to be getting the correct `this` reference. Hence the error. Changing it to use an arrow function should solve the issue.

Example:

```
cameraCheck() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: {
          facingMode: 'environment'
        }
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        this.video.srcObject = stream;
        this.video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'true'); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
        this.video.play();
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Arrow functions work similar to closures, which means they remember  and have access to environment in which they were declared. Hence you are able to access `this` using an arrow function.